# Make antd modal expand according to size of google maps map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, antd

I have a simple antd modal divided using the `Row` and `Col` grid. The Modal expands as needed if I put some content in it on one side, however on the other side I have a map displayed using `google-maps-react`.

The issue here is, I would like the map to be a certain size, but when there is little content, it overflows the modal and looks silly.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
export function MyModal () {
  return (
    <Modal>
     <Row>
        <Col lg={12}>
          [MY CONTENT]
        </Col>
        <Col lg={12}>
          <div>
              <Map google={google}
                initialCenter={{ lat: 45.42, lng: -75.69 }}
                zoom={14}
                style={{ width: 420, height: 400 }}
              />
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

When `MY_CONTENT` does not have much, the map overflows the modal and looks like this:
[image]

However when I am filling in the other side of the modal with content, it naturally expands. So I don't understand why the map does not expand it.

[image]

Anyway the question is how can I make the right side of the modal also expand as much as necessary so that the map fits in it?

Thanks!

Edit: I created a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-antd-it8rr?fontsize=14) so the antd components could be seen. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this on SO's code snippet editor.

Comment: Can you pull a fiddle for this? It seems to be CSS issue to me

Comment: I can't get the google maps component to appear in the sandbox, but this roughly what it looks like: https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-antd-it8rr?fontsize=14

Comment: This is likely an issue with the CSS positioning on the map and not the modal, so it's hard to troubleshoot without an example.  You can try giving the map's container a ```min-height``` if you know how big it should be, or setting it to ```position: relative``` and giving it a percentage height, but you'd have to adjust all the parent containers as well as the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was because my `Map` component was an iframe.
I learned that when this is the case, it doesn't bring in its own width and height, so the parent div thinks it's all 0 or something like that.

The solution was for me to put a width and height on the div. Since this is static on the map anyway, it isn't a problem. So now my code looks like this:

```
export function MyModal () {
  return (
    <Modal>
     <Row>
        <Col lg={12}>
          [MY CONTENT]
        </Col>
        <Col lg={12}>
          <div style={{ width: 420, height: 400 }}>
              <Map google={google}
                initialCenter={{ lat: 45.42, lng: -75.69 }}
                zoom={14}
                style={{ width: 420, height: 400 }}
              />
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```